# Customize JQuery Mobile iOS Theme

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, themes

I found the JQuery Mobile iOS inspired theme here:https://github.com/taitems/iOS-Inspired-jQuery-Mobile-Theme. While I admire it, ideally I would like to customize it. My question is, can I modify this using the JQuery Mobile Theme Roller (http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/). Or, do I need to do it the hard way? I couldn't figure out how to customize it via the themeroller. However, i've not tried to import a theme previously. I was hoping someone may have some tips for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Probably not directly in the ThemeRoller, no. The ThemeRoller allows you to import themes it produced to customize it, but copying & pasting the CSS from https://raw.github.com/taitems/iOS-Inspired-jQuery-Mobile-Theme/master/ios_inspired/styles.css is not recognized. Looks like you may have to do it the old fashioned way.